# Searching an array based on one of its fields

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of class, class has 2 fields: a letter and a number.

I'm looking for a way to write:

For each field that contains a specified letter, do something with number.

I know I can do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Array.Length ; i++)
    if(Array[i].letter == 'a') do something with Array[i].number
```

Is there a way to write that down using foreach loop or is this the correct way?

EDIT: "do something" in my case will mean: (i'm gonna need a third field in class, let's call it test, type bool, and 3 int variables, x = 0 and y = 0, and z = some number I calculated earlier)

```
if(Array[i].letter == 'a')
    if(Array[i].test == false)
        if(Array[i].number < z) x++;
        else y++;
```

Comment: If you can clarify "*do something*" we can be more helpful. Is it sum, average, exclusion?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? It seems perfectly valid to me

Comment: there is no difference if you use foreach or for here. What is the problem you are having? it seems perfectly valid. Also curious to know if there is a reason why you are not using either a List of KeyValuePair or a Dictionary?

Comment: You have several ways to operate on collection type, from simple iteration loops, concurrent , LINQ and ect...
It basically depends on what  you want to do.

Comment: @user3021830 I added explanation

Sayse I know it is correct, I'm just wondering if it's the best approach

Comment: I would say it is, you can use a foreach but you won't gain much from it other than arguably a little bit of readability (scoped variable). Its clear and concise which is what you can really hope for here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your class looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    public char MyLetter { get; set; }
    public bool Test { get; set; }
}
```

and you've got a `List<MyClass>` named *myList*.

If you wanted to iterate through every instance of the class where the letter is A, you could use LINQ for that:

```
foreach (MyClass myClass in myList.Where(c => c.MyLetter == 'A'))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number: " + myClass.MyNumber);
}
```

EDIT: Updated example for your updated question:

```
foreach (MyClass myClass in myList.Where(c => c.MyLetter == 'a' && !c.Test))
{
    if (myClass.MyNumber < z)
        x++;
    else
        y++;
}
```

Comment: With the last iteration variable, remember that `class` is a keyword.

Comment: As I am quite new to these constructions, can you clarify what's the difference between MyClass and myClass please?

Comment: @Januszoff In my example, `MyClass` is the name of the class and `myClass` is the name of a variable containing an instance of that class. Read more about the foreach loop [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). Read more about classes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx).

Comment: @Januszoff No problem! I added an example to match your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following:

```
var newArray = Array.Where(x => x.letter == 'a')
    .Where(x => !x.test)
    .Where(x => x.number < z);
```

Now you have all the elements from your array (btw.: `Array` is a quite bad name for your array). However afterwards you have to loop the new array using `for` or `foreach`.

EDIT: Ofc. you could also join your where-clauses:

```
var newArray = Array.Where(x => x.letter == 'a' && !x.test && x.number <z)
```

but this seems bit ugly, at least to me... It´s up to you.

Comment: I used Array name just as an example, I have like 8 of those in code.

Comment: You should be able to join these as 1 lambda expression. .Where(x => x.letter == 'a' && !x.test && x.number < z);

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your array is filled with objects that are of type MyClass.

```
foreach(MyClass obj in Array) {
    if(obj.letter == 'a') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do what you are after with linq..

```
var valids = arrayName.Where(i => i.letter =='a' && !i.test);
var x = valids.Count(i => i.number < z);
var y = valids.Count() - x;
```

But that doesn't seem any where near as clear as your current approach...

Using a foreach loop would give you a scoped variable which may help if the method expands more.

```
foreach(var item in arrayName)
    if(item.letter == 'a')
        .....
```

But your current approach is clear as to what it is trying to do and looks like it would be easy to maintain.

Your variable names are a bit sketchy however but I'm hoping thats just pseudo code :)